# How to set list of symbles converted to alphabet?

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jtextfield, morse-code

I'm making a system to convert Morse cord to English alphabet. I'm using `JTextfeild` called "write" to type text and another `JTextfeild` call "View" to view which is typed on write.

But I can only set one Morse cord for one time.

As an example if I type `A` on "Write" textfeild it it is only printing ".-" . And when I type "B" again then view textfeild set "-..." . I want to print number of letters.

Given below is my source cord.

```
private void writeKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                  

    if (evt.getKeyCode() == 65) {
        view.setText(".-");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 66) {
        view.setText("-...");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 67) {
        view.setText("-.-.");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 68) {
        view.setText("-..");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 69) {
        view.setText(".");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 70) {
        view.setText("..-.");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 71) {
        view.setText("--.");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 72) {
        view.setText("....");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 73) {
        view.setText("..");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 74) {
        view.setText(".---");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 75) {
        view.setText(".-.-");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 76) {
        view.setText(".-..");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 77) {
        view.setText("--");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 78) {
        view.setText("-.");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 79) {
        view.setText("---");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 80) {
        view.setText(".--.");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 81) {
        view.setText("--.-");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 82) {
        view.setText(".-.");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 83) {
        view.setText("...");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 84) {
        view.setText("-");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 85) {
        view.setText("..-");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 86) {
        view.setText("...-");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 87) {
        view.setText(".--");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 88) {
        view.setText("-..-");
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == 89) {
        view.setText("-.--");
    } else {
        view.setText("--..");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm making a system to convert Mose cord to English alphabet. I'm
>   using jtextfeild called "write" to type text and another jtextfeild
>   call "View" to view which is typed on write.

- use `DocumentListener` for `JTextComponent`s instead of low_level `KeyListener`, otheriwise you can't be able to input sequence of chars from (for example) `Ctrl+C` (SystemClipBoard), or remove selected chars, then output to anther `JComponent`s freeze without any, no changes are made, because `KeyListener` can firing an `Event` from single `Char` only
- plus you can use `DocumentFilter` in the case that you want to replace, remove, modify single `char` or `chars sequence` typed by user into `JTextField`

for example

[image]

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class TextLabelMirror {

    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
    private JTextField field1 = new JTextField(20);

    public TextLabelMirror() {
        field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateLabel(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateLabel(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateLabel(e);
            }

            private void updateLabel(DocumentEvent e) {
                java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        field1.setText(field.getText());
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 10, 0));
        mainPanel.add(field);
        mainPanel.add(field1);
    }

    public JComponent getComponent() {
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextLabelMirror");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TextLabelMirror().getComponent());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As I can understand from this cord field1 sets any value typed on feild. I want to specify those typed keys using some symbols(mose cord). so I think I need if else or that sort of selection system.

Comment: not you not need something special, but note you have two choices in  (prerequisities is Map of Morse sing) 1. one enless String contians morse only DocumentListener 2. DocumentListener and DocumentFilter (and/or SPACE is added after block of chars is typped) more logical because you can to block input there for rest of keys from KeyBoard, allowed are only Dot and Minus for concrete JTextField

Comment: I'm using netbeans so can you please show me how to call this documentListner method to designed jtextfeild, without this designing cords. Please can you help me for this.

Comment: sorry I'm not GUI Builder user, but there must be option to add any Listener, or add, insert code I think

Comment: ok can you tell is there any event like documentListner of Jtextfeild is GUI

Comment: hey I used eclipse and this cord is working. But can toy please tell me where I suppose to set this selections, Like A==> ..-- B==> .-- Please reply,

Comment: I think this required to change design, (my view) there could be and array of JButtons with JTextArea, two JPanels (CardLayout or GridLayout for both) one part for Morse to Alphabetical, 2nd vice versa

Comment: selection in JTextArea required to Caret and modelToView, (my current view, never tried) quite not simple to show encoded text from selection, but is possible for someone that make popup from selection in JTextArea/JTextPane, translator or similair (two three persons here), be sure that will be very nice question, maybe great in the case that will be based on your  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I'm so sorry about that. You guys did great help. I'm so glad.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the event that way. Get the 'write' text as string and work on it:

```
private void writeKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    String input = write.getText();
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for(int cIndx = 0; cIndx < input.length(); ++cIndx){
        output.append(convertChar(input.charAt(cIndx)));
    }
}

private String convertChar(char c)
{
    // TODO Your conversion method, modified a little:
    if( c == 'a' || c == 'A')  return ".-";
    if( c == 'b' || c == 'B')  return "-...";
    // etc....
    return ""; // handle as you like this case.
}
```